# Drupal 7 UberCart Volume Pricing with Role Based Pricing Support

Tags: 7, ubercart

I have scenario where the default UberCart  Volume Pricing should support user role based pricing.

Fox example : If I have a product, it pricing has to configured in such a way that

For  user role 1 - with minimum of 'x' quantity - its price has to be some '$a'.

For user role 2 - with minimum of 'y' quantity - its price has to be some '$b'.

In short, I am satisfied with the functionalities of these both modules ([Ubercart Volume Pricing](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_volume_pricing), [Ubercart Price Per Role](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_price_per_role)) individually and would like to combine the functionalities of these both.

If anyone have solution for this, can you please share it?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/2567049